# AS3 Should i removeEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a pretty complex game with many views and many controllers, and it works really well but periodically lags. I am trying to fix up my code so it's as efficient as i can make it, but i have some questions as to who AS3 handles events.

Now here is a very basic example:

AppController loads 5 different OverlayControllers. Each one of those OverlayControllers dispatch an Event.COMPLETE when they are done that my AppController listens to. I have a constant EventListener listening to those OverlayControlllers no matter where I am in the game.

Should i only have those listeners there when the Overlay is open? And Remove them when they close?

Should i bypass the event listener period and just pass the AppController to the OverlayControllers so it can just call a public function instead of requiring an EventListener?

Just to be clear these aren't objects that i'm removing from the stage. They are just being hidden. If i ever remove an object i always remove its event listeners before destroying them.

Comment: Listening to events does not produce lags in any case, dispatching events could on the other hand if many are dispatched constantly. When having lag problems events are rarely involved, what's very likely the case is high object creation which result on heavy GC passes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all download Adobe Scout (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html) and see what's causing the "lags" - probably garbage collection ...then fix the issue. Removing as many listeners as possible is always a good thing but make sure that those are causing the issue. Profile memory usage and try to keep object creation/destruction to a minimum to avoid garbage collection (during the main game loop).

Comment: And if the load is caused by a lot of object creation / destruction and you have a lot of the same objects - you might need to implement object pooling